# Failing to find a match when using serde_xml_rs with enums

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to deserialize XML block with serde_xml_rs but for some reason it doesn't seem to be able to identify and map the result on my enum. Here is the code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
enum Type {
    #[serde(rename = "string")]
    StringFieldEmpty,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
struct DataType {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    #[serde(rename = "$value")]
    dtype: Type,
}

// Code to test with
let basic_test = r#"
    <dataType name="My object">
    <description>
        Describes my object.
    </description>
    <string>
    </string>
    </dataType>
    "#;

let data_basic_type: DataType = from_str(basic_test).unwrap();
```

There will be different types of data types than "string" and even "string"-type will have elements like maxLength=69 inside it so enum is very much needed here.

I'm getting error...

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { field: "unknown variant `description`, expected `string`" }
```

Any suggestions for solving this are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I cracked this. First of all, migrating into quick_xml helped to move forward with the solution as it was more permissive (rename = "string" started working). However, the real problem was in the fact that in **serde** one cannot rely on order and thus $value would take try to take any field (and in this case *description*) and not just *string* requiring a solution where I can define the applicable keys.

Using combination of rename and alias tags solved this for me. Here are the key changes...

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
enum Type {
    #[serde(rename = "string")]
    StringField(StringType),
    #[serde(rename = "unsignedInt")]
    UnsignedInt,
    #[serde(rename = "unsignedLong")]
    UnsignedLong,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
struct DataType {
    name: String,
    base: Option<String>,
    description: String,
    #[serde(rename = "string")]
    #[serde(alias = "unsignedInt")]
    #[serde(alias = "unsignedLong")]
    dtype: Type,
}
```